# The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional

Tags: typescript

Estou com dificuldade de entender porque não é possível aplicar o delete user.password no código abaixo

Retorno do terminal:

> The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional.

Meu código:

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { getRepository } from 'typeorm';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

import User from '../models/User';

class AuthController {
  async authenticate(req: Request, res: Response){
    const repository = getRepository(User);

    const { email, password } = req.body;

    const user = await repository.findOne({
      where: { email }
    });

    if(!user) {
      return res.sendStatus(401);
    }

    const isValidPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if(!isValidPassword) {
      return res.sendStatus(401);
    }
        
    const token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id}, 'secret', { expiresIn: '1d'});
 
    delete user.password;
 
    return res.json({
      user,
      token,
    });
  }
}

export default new AuthController();
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Este erro foi introduzido na versão 4.0, e é uma das [*breaking changes*](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-wiki/blob/master/Breaking-Changes.md#operands-for-delete-must-be-optional):

> When using the `delete` operator in `strictNullChecks`, the operand must now be `any`, `unknown`, `never`, or be optional (in that it contains `undefined` in the type). Otherwise, use of the delete operator is an error.

Ou seja, o TypeScript alertará sobre o uso de `delete` em uma propriedade que não é *opcional*, visto que isso estaria quebrando o contrato da interface.

### Resolvendo o erro

Para evitar esse problema, faça da `password` uma propriedade opcional ou crie uma nova interface para isso. Por exemplo:

```js
interface User {
    name: string;
    password: string;
}

const user: User = { name: 'Rafael', password: '123' };
delete user.password;
// Acima não permite a remoção porque tornaria a tipagem inconsistente, quebrando o contrato da interface


interface User2 {
    name: string;
    password?: string;
}

const user2: User2 = { name: 'Rafael', password: '123' };
delete user2.password;
// Como `password` pode ser `undefined`, o TypeScript não reporta erro algum
```

<sup>Veja o exemplo no [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChkHIhwC2EAXMumFKAOYDc%20hADnOugO4D2UAJpWq0QjXAF9cuBNxDVkAV0xRKGLAF4cRUhWQByAEpx4EADa6ANMjYce-SroCMAJgDMu5GKZ9TESAqUAdNZcvHxMkrigkLCIKKpQTjjMBMRkgjT0TIRW7CH8APzpwqISUjJyitBOKkqJGthaaXqGxmaWwbYCes5uHl4%20fpUJQbmdDEA).</sup>

---

### Ignorando o erro (*não recomendado*)

Existe uma alternativa que colocarei aqui apenas para deixar registrado, mas é bom evitá-la porque ela não resolve o problema, apenas faz com que o TypeScript "pare de reclamar":

```
// @ts-expect-error Aqui vai ocorrer um erro, mas estou ignorando
delete user.password;
```

<sup>Veja no [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChkHIhwC2EAXMumFKAOYDc%20hADnOugO4D2UAJpWq0QjXAF9cuBNxDVkAV0xRKGLAF4cRUhWQByAEpx4EADa6ANMjYce-SroCMAJgDMu5GKYB6L8gACYOgAtBAAHiwQCGAhUFC8yACCAI7ywMgAbnBp3NKxWPIkyNBxliTsRdTc8sjAdCC8cCB83Lh8phCQCkoAdNZcvHwMQA).</sup>

Essa não é uma boa alternativa porque caso você vá usar a variável `user` posteriormente, o TypeScript não irá apontar que o `password` pode ser `undefined`. Ou seja, o contrato da interface foi quebrado e ninguém sabe disso, pode causar problemas no futuro.

É melhor pensar num jeito de ter tudo consistente mesmo que seja um pouco mais verboso, afinal, se foi decidido usar tipagens com TypeScript, esforçe-se para usá-las direito.

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra solução seria completar o seu padrão MVC - Models,
Views,
Controllers.
Dessa forma vc pode padronizar a resposta que deseja retornar sem este tipo de alteração mais bruta.

Ou seja ... crie uma pasta views com o arquivo userViews.ts com o seguinte código:

```
import User from '../models/User';

export default {
  render(user: User){
    return {
      id: user.id,
      email: user.email,
      // aqui vc poderá acrescentar futuramente novos campos que serão retornados
    };
  }
}
```

Após a criação da View, mude o retorno da sua autenticação para:

```
 return res.json({
  user: usersView.render(user),
  token,
});
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Também não se esqueça de importar sua View de usuários no seu controller de autenticação é claro.

import usersView from '../views/UsersViews';

Answer (score 0):

Existe um caminho mais simples que modificar o código. (pois é básico a obrigatoriedade do password)

No seu arquivo tsconfig.json procure por 'strictNullChecks', retire o comentário dessa opção e deixe como false. assim:

```
"strictNullChecks": false,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
```

Salve seu arquivo e volte ao código! ;)

caso tenha limpado seu arquivo, apenas adicione essa linha!

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Na maioria das vezes, em um projeto que já começou com o `strictNullChecks` ativado, isso, pelo menos na minha opinião, causaria mais mal do que bem, porque tornaria alguns códigos mais suscetíveis a erro ligados ao `null` e `undefined`, que outrora estavam sendo prevenidos pela _flag_ em questão. O assunto da pergunta é, inclusive, um bug prevenido pela _flag_. Enfim, se é para “burlar”, desativando a opção, a segurança que o TypeScript traz, nem vale a pena utilizá-lo...