# Problema ao deletar password das Rotas de Autenticação

Tags: react, typescript

estou tendo o seguinte erro *The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional.* ao tentar deletar o password do user nas rotas de autenticação, para que não vá essa informação para o frontend.
Porém o typescript acusa esse erro. Procurando a respeito achei uma informação que teria que passar o operando '?' na interface de User que resolveria, porém o erro persiste, a interface está em outro arquivo separado do routes.

Segue os arquivos.

**sessions.routes.ts**

```
import { Router } from 'express';

import AuthenticateUserService from '../services/AuthenticateUserService';

const sessionsRouter = Router();

sessionsRouter.post('/', async (request, response) => {
  const { email_user, password_user } = request.body;

  const authenticateUser = new AuthenticateUserService();

  const { user, token } = await authenticateUser.execute({
    email_user,
    password_user,
  });

  delete user.password_user;

  return response.json({ user, token });
});

export default sessionsRouter;
```

**AuthenticateUserService.ts**

```
import { getRepository } from 'typeorm';
import { compare } from 'bcryptjs';
import { sign } from 'jsonwebtoken';
import authConfig from '../config/auth';

import AppError from '../errors/AppError';

import User from '../models/User';

interface Request {
  email_user: string;
  password_user?: string;
}

interface Response {
  user: User;
  token: string;
}

class AuthenticateUserService {
  public async execute({
    email_user,
    password_user,
  }: Request): Promise<Response> {
    const userRepository = getRepository(User);

    const user = await userRepository.findOne({ where: { email_user } });

    if (!user) {
      throw new AppError('Incorrect email/password combination.', 401);
    }

    if (!password_user) {
      throw new AppError('Incorrect email/password combination.', 401);
    }

    const passwordMatched = await compare(password_user, user.password_user);

    if (!passwordMatched) {
      throw new AppError('Incorrect email/password combination.', 401);
    }

    const { secret, expiresIn } = authConfig.jwt;

    const token = sign({}, secret, {
      subject: user.id_user,
      expiresIn,
    });

    return {
      user,
      token,
    };
  }
}

export default AuthenticateUserService;
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/479147/the-operand-of-a-delete-operator-must-be-optional)

Comment: Não resolve amigo, porque no meu **sessions.route.ts** o **user** já recebe **User** do **AuthenticateUserService.ts** então não consigo associar o **interface User2**